# Copying Interpolated/Extrapolated Data Table from MATLAB Figure for Use in Another Application

Tags: windows, matlab, clipboard

I have a MATLAB figure where I performed interpolation/extrapolation on some data points, and the result is displayed in a table within the figure window. I need to copy this table of data and paste it into another application (e.g., Excel or a text editor) for further analysis.

[image]
Here's what I've tried so far:

I opened the figure and accessed the interpolated/extrapolated data table.
I selected the data within the table.
I used the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + C to copy the selected data.
However, when I try to paste the copied data into another application, the formatting seems to be lost or the data doesn't paste as expected.

I'm wondering if there's a specific method or approach I should be using to ensure that the copied table data retains its formatting and structure when pasted into a different application. Is there something I'm missing or a step I need to take before copying the data? Are there any potential compatibility issues between MATLAB and the target application that I should be aware of?

Any guidance or advice on how to successfully copy and paste this interpolated/extrapolated data table from the MATLAB figure to another application would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!